# hive metastore with external mysql does not work

Tags: mysql, hive, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I was trying to get my external mysql be used as a hive metastore in Ambari. These are the steps I followed

```
- Started a HDInsight in Azure
- create a mysql database
- create a database 'metastore' and a user 'hive' in mysql
- source 'Ambari-DDL-AzureDB-CREATE.sql' to create schema in metastore db
- changed the mysql connection in hive config using Amabri UI
- Tested the mysql connection and it was connected
```

When I restarted the metastore service of hive, it failed with error
"Cannot find tables 'DBS' and 'Version' in metastore database.

When I checked the metastore database, it did not had these tables.
How to create these tables?

What am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using hive schematool.

Comment: Awesome. Have a great day.